# Can I use Paypal without server side programming and show a code once the transaction is completed?

Tags: web-applications, paypal

I'm trying to set up a system whereby a user clicks a button, is taken to PayPal and receives a code once they've paid. I know that there are ways to do this using PHP (which I'm not familiar with). I'm hoping I can do it more simply as follows.

1. Create a code in my app from the userID and add it as a variable to the PayPal button html.
2. Send code to PayPal when button is clicked.
3. Show code once transaction is completed.

Is there a way to send a variable and have it displayed after a transaction? This seems like an obvious and simple process to me, but I'm not familiar with PayPal's charging system.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this via the API, FORM [Variables](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) or both. If you're looking for a solution or examples, then Pro Webmasters would be off-topic because it's about HTML and API programming, Stack Overflow is more suitable if so.